# Refreshing Datatables

Tags: kohana-3, datatables

I am updating my table using ajax, the process is not tied to the datatables and I would like to perform a table refresh

```
$('#listing').dataTable( {
        "bDestroy": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "getlist/",
            "bJQueryUI": true,


            "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "id" },      
        { "mDataProp": "aname" },           
        { "mDataProp": "acode" },
        { "mDataProp": "editlink" },
                    { "mDataProp": "deletelink" },

    ],
            "aoColumnDefs": [ 
                    { "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }

    ]



} );
```

My data is customized to appear as `{"aaData":[{"id":"14",` and its working well because the table is being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the datatable by calling `fnDraw()` method. However the Datatables will read the data again from the actual data source (Ajax URI, in your case) **ONLY** if **`bServerSide: true`** is set (by which you are telling the Datatables that all the processing is done at server side).

One side effect of `bServerSide: true` is that you need send the pagination details (iTotalRecords & iTotalDisplayRecords, .. ) & other data in the Ajax response (see [Server-side Processing](http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side) docs).

Othre side effect is that filtering will not work any longer :( Datatable can't filter the partial data which it has.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables has an fnReloadAjax function in the API that you can paste into your script: [fnReloadAjax](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax).  And you don't need to have serverside processing enabled for this to work either.

A word of caution though: if you plan on incorporating a repeating refresh (i.e. the table refreshes every 10 seconds to display "live" data) the best way to do so is to periodically identify modified data from your AJAX source (perhaps by comparing a "modified" timestamp in your records) and using [fnAddData](http://www.datatables.net/ref#fnAddData) to add / update / remove just those rows.  This will be less expensive for the client than reloading the entire dataset each time.